# How does Ruby on Rails use yield for layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, block, yield

`yield` is used to call a block. How does this work in Rails where `yield` is used for layouts?

```
-# application.html.haml
%body= yield
```

Does it use blocks somewhere or is the method simply overridden?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Technically, `yield` is calling a block in this context as well. However, the block is the view your controller action was told to render.

For example, let's say you have a `StaticContentController` that has an `index` action on it that represented your home page. With routes configured correctly, you visit your home page. Rails will load the layout file in `views/layouts` that is appropriate for that controller (`application.html.haml`, unless you overrode this with a layout for your controller). When it reaches the `yield` command, it inserts the view at `views/static_content/index.html.haml` at the location where `yield` is inside your layout. Then, it loads the rest of your layout file.

Answer (score 9):

By default all Ruby functions can be passed a block:

```
def twice
  yield
  yield
end

> twice { print 'hi ' }
=> hi hi
```

The best way to think of a layout is a method that is called with a block.

When Rails renders a template, it is actually making a call to Layout#render.  Layout#render accepts a default block.  By default Rails passes your view as this block.  This means that calling yield from within your layout is like calling the default block, which in this case is your view.